# java to connect Microsoft dynamics 365

Tags: java, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to connect Microsoft dynamics 365 CRM using java, I can only see this(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602979(v=crm.5).aspx) link for the java connection. Can anyone please tell me how to connect ms dynamics using java.

My only need is to load the contacts from CRM to my appplication.

Comment: What have you already tried and were do you struggle?

Comment: I tried to connect ms dynamics crm by using Axis 2 and httpclient with the help of above link, I can able to create ,update and delete account and contacts in the crm but when I try to load contacts from server i got some exception  org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts}KeyAttributes

Answer (score 3):

You should use the [WebAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt593051.aspx).

> The Web API, which is new for Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online &
>   on-premises), provides a development experience that can be used
>   across a wide variety of programming languages, platforms, and
>   devices. The Web API implements the OData (Open Data Protocol),
>   version 4.0, an OASIS standard for building and consuming RESTful APIs
>   over rich data sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [GitHub example](https://github.com/gregdegruy/dynamics-rest-with-adal/blob/master/dynamicscrmapi/src/main/java/Main.java). I use adal4j to take care of all the auth overhead and it gives me a bearer token that I can use to make api calls to my organization.

```
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;
import okhttp3.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
        String resource = "https://msott.crm.dynamics.com";
        String clientId = "64f4cba8-0656-4ccd-8c2a-fd269fe7636f";
        String clientSecret = "";
        String tenantID = "grdegr.onmicrosoft.com";
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        AuthenticationResult result;

        try {
            AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenantID, true, service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(resource, new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), null);

            result = future.get();
            String accessToken = result.getAccessToken();

            createWithDataReturned(accessToken);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) { }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        catch (ExecutionException e) { }
    }

    // TODO: 5
    // Retrieving customized responses on POST method:
    public static void createWithDataReturned(String accessToken) {
        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{" +
                    "\"name\": \"Sample Postman Account\"," +
                    "\"creditonhold\": false," +
                    "\"address1_latitude\": 47.639583," +
                    "\"description\": \"This is the description of the sample account\"," +
                    "\"revenue\": 5000000," +
                    "\"accountcategorycode\": 1" +
                    "}");
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://msott.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/accounts?$select=name,creditonhold,address1_latitude,description,revenue,accountcategorycode,createdon")
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0")
                    .addHeader("OData-Version", "4.0")
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                    .addHeader("Prefer", "return=representation")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .addHeader("Postman-Token", "472f1651-c4e1-47c1-8a5c-6f70636181b0")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            String dataReturnedFromCreate = response.body().string();

            System.out.println();
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

I'm using these Maven packages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mrrobot</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamicscrmapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>adal4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```